# How to filter F-Droid (MediaWiki) recent changes by package name?

Tags: rss, mediawiki, mediawiki-api, fdroid

[F-Droid](https://f-droid.org) offers a page of **recent changes** both as HTML and RSS:

- https://f-droid.org/wiki/index.php?title=Special:RecentChanges&days=30&from=&hidebots=0&hideanons=1&hideliu=1&limit=500
- https://f-droid.org/wiki/api.php?action=feedrecentchanges&limit=500

The RSS does not show the same content. It seems to be truncated. Applying the same parameters as with the HTML link causes all `<item>` elements to be dropped.

I like to filter the RSS (and optionally the HTML) by a specific package name. Is this possible?

## Related

- https://f-droid.org/wiki/api.php
- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page
- https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=feedrecentchanges

Comment: Not exactly an answer to my question but an alternative: there is various **API endpoints** for F-Droid which are documented in the [F-Droid Build Status project](https://codeberg.org/pstorch/F-Droid_Build_Status/).